# Unable to send array with post method and to query multiple items to DB

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am creating an array with a while for each item that I have saved on my DB and is being displayed with checkboxes to allow the user to select which ones they'll be using, but I am not able to send those items..

this is what I am using to display each item and is being displayed on my screen with each id of the table and the exercise assigned to that id

```
<?php while ($row7 = mysqli_fetch_array($result7)):;?>
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="<?php $row7['id_detalle_plan'];?>"><?php echo $row7['ejercicio'];?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

and this is what I am using to save the array but I guess something is missing on my code

```
foreach ($_POST["array"] as $elementos){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario_detalle_plan(id_detalle_plan,id_usuario) 
            values('$elementos','$idusuario');INSERT INTO detalle_plan_has_dia(id_detalle_plan,id_dia) 
            values('$elementos','$id_dia')";
    mysqli_multi_query($db,$sql);                        
}
```

I just want to save the selected items from the checkboxes but those checkboxes are created with the WHILE that I used to display them